# Смена переменной при клике на определенную кнопку

Tags: javascript

уважаемые гуру javascripta 
Бьюсь второй день над вроде бы простой задачей, но не хватает базовых знаний
Подскажите как мне реализовать при клике на кнопку подставлять определенную переменную?

```js
var month = ['Mar 1',2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30];
var year = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
var ever = [2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020];

//В эту переменную хочу подставить одну из тех что выше при клике
var time;


var ctx = document.getElementById('graph-mobile').getContext("2d");

var graph_mobile = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: time,
        datasets: [
        {
            label: "Fd",
            borderColor: gradientFd,
            pointRadius: 3,
            pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: gradientFd,
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: fd,
            lineTension: 0
        },
        {
            label: "Er",
            borderColor: gradientEr,
            pointRadius: 3,
            pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: gradientEr,
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: er,
            lineTension: 0
        }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(30, 37, 73, 0.5)',
            titleFontFamily: 'inherit',
            height: '100%',
            position:'nearest',
            bodyFontColor: '#a9b2e1',
            bodyFontSize:14,
            bodySpacing:30,
            xPadding:20,
            yPadding:25,
            cornerRadius:0,
            multiKeyBackground: 'transparent',
            enabled: true
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: true
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
            display:false,
            position: "right",
            labels: {
                fontColor: '#54F0FF',
                fontSize: '14',
                lineHeight: '20px',
                usePointStyle:true,
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "#6673B4",
                    maxTicksLimit: 5,
                    padding: 14,
                    display:false,
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                gridLines: {
                    drawTicks: true,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    color: "rgba(102, 115, 180, 0.2)"
                }

            }],
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    zeroLineColor: "#fff",
                    display: false
                },
                ticks: {
                    padding: 8,
                    fontColor: "#6673B4",
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

    //Вот мой кусок кода который остался
    $('.tabs a').click(function () {
        $('.tabs a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.x-git.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:;">Month</a>
  <a class="" href="javascript:;">Year</a>
  <a class="" href="javascript:;">Ever</a>
</div>
<div class="graph-mobile">
  <canvas id="graph-mobile"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что сработает, предлагаю на проверку*

5 минут гугла привели меня сюда — https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html 

И скорее всего код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
$('.tabs a').on('click', function () {
  $('.tabs a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  if( this.innerText == 'Month'){
    time = month;
  } else if( this.innerText == 'Year'){
    time = year;
  } else if( this.innerText == 'Ever' ){
    time = ever;
  }
  graph_mobile.data.labels = time;
  graph_mobile.update();
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nikoaldr/cr78txbk/2/
в песочнице сработало, разбираюсь на рабочем проекте

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.tabs a').click(function() {
  var data_time = $(this).attr('data-time');

  if (data_time == 'month') {
    var time = ['Mar 1', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30];
  }

  if (data_time == 'year') {
    var time = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  }

  if (data_time == 'ever') {
    var time = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020];
  }

  console.info(time);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)" data-time="month">Month</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-time="year">Year</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-time="ever">Ever</a>
</div>
```